# Characterizations of convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $X = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a finite set of points in the plane. No $3$ of them are collinear.

I am trying to think of ways to characterize the convex hull $\operatorname{conv}(X)$. Here is one particular attempt I'm intersted in:

1. For every vector $v=(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, write $v^\perp=(-y,x)$.
2. A pair of indices $1\leq i,j\leq n$ is a *maximal pair* if $\langle (x_j-x_i)^\perp,x_i\rangle=\max_k\{\langle (x_j-x_i)^\perp,x_k\rangle\}=:t_{i,j}$.
3. Every maximal pair $i,j$ defines a halfplane $H_{i,j}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid\langle (x_j-x_i)^\perp,x\rangle \leq t_{i,j}\}$. Clearly, $X \subset H_{i,j}$.
4. Let $M$ be the set of maximal pairs. Define $D=\cap_{(i,j)\in M} H_{i,j}$.

Obviously, $D$ is a convex set containing $X$. So, $\operatorname{conv}(X)\subset D$.

Intuitively, it looks like we actually have $\operatorname{conv}(X)=D$. The idea is that the maximal pairs seem to correspond to the sides of the convex hull.

> Is $\operatorname{conv}(X)=D$? If so, how can this be proved?

Comment: You'll need to remove the requirement that $i<j$ to make sure that the half-spaces point in the right direction. Also it won't work if the points are collinear.

Comment: @p.s: Ok. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: To be more specific, it won't work if *all* the points lie on a single line, because then D would just be that unbounded line. Otherwise I think it's true, but I can't think of a simple proof offhand.